# Drag and drop check Boxes from one panel to another

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, drag-and-drop, jpanel

I want to drag and drop check boxes from one panel to another in Java. I have found one link which looks quite useful, but it was written back in 1999 and don't know whether it is updated or not.

http://www.javaworld.com/jw-03-1999/jw-03-dragndrop.html?page=2

Comment: It's using the core drag'n'drop API.  Have a try and see what you get ;)

Comment: I am open to using any API. If there is something better, please tell me about that.

Comment: For what you want to achieve, this is probably the best place to start

Comment: Ok, so I would give it a go.